# Hyperledger Fabric - how to change user attributes using nodejs sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I need an ability for admin to change user attributes. My first attempt was try to reenroll user. It does not work, see below. If I revoke yser certificate, and trying to make new one , system says me that user already exists.

I saw [reenroll](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/FabricCAClient.html#reenroll__anchor) function in ca client.

I made reenroll function work and it working only for user who holds certificate. Admin cannot reenroll users. Is there other legal way to change user attributes?

I use nodejs 8 and  1.3.0 sdk for nodejs.

Comment: Which version of sdk you are using?

Comment: 1.3.0. Updated question.

Comment: Does reenroll really work for you? It seems that it is not possible to change attribute values by using reenroll.

Comment: No, it does not. I finished up with revoking old certificate and creating new one  with desired attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the Update function on the IdentityService. This should allow you to update attributes for an already existing user. You will need to do
something like this:

`const req = {
  type: 'testType',
  affiliation: 'testAffiliation',
  maxEnrollments: 42,
  attrs: 'testAtts',
  enrollmentSecret: 'shhh!',
  caname: 'caName'
};
await identity.update('bob', req, registrar);`

I would take a look at this Node test case that shows how to update an identity: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/v1.3.0/fabric-ca-client/test/IdentityService.js#L421